как передать значение переменных из асинхронной функции aiogram
У меня 2 файла с кодом, main.py:
import logging
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

API_TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)

@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    await message.answer(f"Your user_id ({user_id}) has been saved in context.")

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

и хочу чтобы значение user_id из main.py передавалось во 2 файл с кодом. Как можно это сделать? 2 файл пока что пустой, туда я позже добавлю код, а пока хотел там проверить правильно ли передается user_id пользователя, как можно это реализовать?

Покажите 2 файл куда вы хотите отдать значение

2 файл пока пустой, его я заполню позже, а пока хочу проверить будет ли передаваться user_id пользователя, буду проверять через print

Во втором файле пишем:
from main import user_id
print(user_id)

или
print(main.user_id)

main - название первого файла

если ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его как решение.

Там выходит ошибка: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mac/Documents/pythonProject/second_file.py", line 2, in 
print(file.user_id)
AttributeError: module 'file' has no attribute 'user_id'

тогда пользуйтесь импортом файла

так это тоже не работает, там же пишет нет атрибута user_id
